# Build React app with express backend for domain http://example.com

Tags: reactjs, forms, express, contacts

I have a web application in React that I needed to implement a contact form. The application is created using create-react-app and the server folder added. For the form I used sendgrid mail. Does the server work on port 4567, how do the app build to work on the domain? It is a one-page application.

Thx, it is important.

Comment: What have you tried? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

When running in production, a React app is simple HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. These files are sent from your server to a client when requested in the same way that requests/responses are handled for any web page. There are a few steps that need to be done before your React app is ready for production

**1: Create a Production Build**

First you need to create a production build of your app. This process takes all of your separate `.js` or `.jsx` files and puts them together into a single minified file, and the same for `.css`. Then your `index.html` is updated to include a `link` to the CSS and `script` to the JS. This is done so that only three files will need to be sent rather than the 10s or 100s that exist in development.

If you used `create-react-app` to start your application, you can use the command:

```
npm run build
```

to do this. Otherwise, you need to have [webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack) installed, and then run:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.prod.js --mode production
```

(which you might want to add as a script to `package.json`).

See [React: Optimizing Performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html) for more.

**2. Serve your Application**

Now your server should have a route for your application and when it receives a request on that route, the server should respond by sending `index.html` from your `client/build/` directory (where `client/` is the directory of the React app).

Here is an example with Node/Express as the server (in `app.js`):

```
const path = require('path');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname), 'client', 'build', 'index.html');
});
```

Note that this is just the way to send a static file using Node and can easily be done with any server.

**Additional**

You mentioned you want to submit forms with your application. If your routes for receiving POST requests match the routes that the forms are on (e.g. form is on `/form` and server listens for POST on `/form`) you can just use the default HTML form submission. However this is not a great way to do things when using React because then routing will be controlled by your server rather than by React. Instead you should use some sort of AJAX method to submit the form.

Since your server is now serving your React app (rather than React serving itself as in development), you can just make relative requests and those requests will be made to your server. For example the request (using the fetch API):

```
const models = await fetch('/api/models');
```

Will be made to `your_host/api/models` by default.

Answer (score 0):

in the package.json add

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4567"
```

Comment: thx for your response, but i need not on localhost but on real domain